# Ping Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, ping

I have a Client Application that works directly with an Azure Hosted WCF Service, I would like to consistently `PING` my service to ensure a consistent and stable connection, as my client application requires a consistent connection to function properly.

Is there any method to do this?

Comment: Have you thought about just adding a simple "Hello World" service method? Then call it like you would call any other service method.

Comment: Then what, time the communication with a `Stopwatch`?

Comment: Sure, if you're trying to track how fast, just have a local service that starts a stopwatch, makes the call, checks the time elapsed, and if it either failed or took too long, send a notification to the admin, or whatever it is you want to do. But the ping service itself can just be a straightforward `public string Hello(string name){return "Hello " + name; }` method.

Comment: Not a bad idea! I'll try that! =D

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Web App monitoring should work for you. You can also create a web page just for the endpoint monitoring. For example, you can add several check ups before returning STATUS 200 OK on your Web Service. Here's a step by step to enable a simple rule of Response Time monitoring.

1. Navigate to your website, select configure tab;
2. Scroll to Monitoring Section >> Endpoints. Add a name, url, select one or more data centers as test locations;
3. Go to Monitor tab, click Add Metrics;
4. Select Endpoints Tab >> Check all that applies to your use case;
5. On Monitor list >> Select Response Time >> Click Add Rule;
6. Give it a Name, Description >> Choose condition threshold >> Check Send an email to the service administrator;
7. Apply